# Azure DevOps Artifact Agent log "Error: UPGRADE FAILED: timed out waiting for the condition"

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So the CD part was working perfectly fine for a whole year, now without any changes it started giving this error. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

This is the command that gets executed:

[image]

Comment: Hi, could you kindly provide more information for trouble-shooting? The release definition and debug log will be helpful in the issue. But please remove all the personal information (include accounts, token etc.) in the files and edit your question. And have you tried other versions of helm for a try to see whether the version of your previous tasks now don't support the current used helm? Thanks

Comment: Hi @AntoniaWu-MSFT , I've added the command that fails. it runs by a deployment agent job in azure artifat? not sure what other details to add

Comment: Hi, according to your comment it seems you use self-hosted agent run the task in release pipelines. Since the time out issue may relate to the agent communication issue, could you tell whether it runs well if you run the task locally in the machine which install the self-hosted agent for a try? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here has nothing to do with Kubernetes or the AKS cluster( that was my first thought) I tried deploying manually using the same commands I set up in the CD pipeline, I figured that my docker image was broken and wasn't matching the latest helm release.

I solved it by replicating the issue manually (both CI and CD) and inspecting the pipeline in debug mode.